# concatenating df in a loop without append in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this code written to load all files in a folder and to work on them one by one and to create a df which will contain them all. this is using the append which make it a list with the numpy which changes the structure.

```
np_array_list = []
for file in folder:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
    #
    #here I do more work on the files I import
    #
    merged = pd.df
    merged.to_csv('2017_'+str(Time)+'_min_'+os.path.basename(file)+'_merged.csv')
    np_array_list.append(merged.as_matrix())
    print(merged.head(5))

comb_np_array = np.vstack(np_array_list)
#print(comb_np_array)
big_frame = pd.DataFrame(comb_np_array)
big_frame.to_csv('test.csv')
```

My problem is that the the big_frame is like this:

```
[5 rows x 47 columns]
[[2.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.25698594e+04 ... 1.64000000e+02
  1.25715000e+04 3.00000000e+01]
 [2.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 1.25775858e+04 ... 2.25000000e+02
  1.25795000e+04 4.40000000e+01]
 [2.00000000e+00 2.00000000e+00 1.25800000e+04 ... 2.38000000e+02
  1.25805000e+04 1.80000000e+01]
```

while the expected should look like this:

```
        hour    minute  k1_UNfiltered   k2_UNfiltered   k3_UNfiltered   k4_UNfiltered   k5_UNfiltered
            max                 
1min                                
2017-09-19  02:00:00    2   0   12561.604167    12565.5 12559   12565   12556
2017-09-19  02:01:00    2   1   12560.077922    12562.5 12562   12562.5 12557
2017-09-19  02:02:00    2   2   12558.45    12559.5 12557   12559.5 12557
2017-09-19  02:03:00    2   3   12556.253623    12560   12559.5 12560   12553
2017-09-19  02:04:00    2   4   12555.944444    12557   12556.5 12556.5 12555
```

pls advice how to fix this
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need append each `DataFrame` to list `L` and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
L = []
for file in folder:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
    #
    #here I do more work on the files I import
    #
    merged = pd.df
    merged.to_csv('2017_'+str(Time)+'_min_'+os.path.basename(file)+'_merged.csv')
    L.append(merged)
    print(merged.head(5))

big_frame = pd.concat(L)
```